# два тела, два села - where is the accent placed?

Tags: родительный-падеж, ударение

When we say "два тела" and "два села", where have the nouns тела and села the accent ? On the first syllable or on the last one ?
I ask this because the noun тело has the Nominative plural accentuated on the ending: те**ла**, whilst the Genitive singular is accentuated on the first syllable: **те**ла. And the noun село has an opposite accentuation: the Nominative plural accentuated on the first syllable: **сё**ла, whilst the Genitive singular is accentuated on the ending: се**ла**.

Thank you!

Comment: _два, три, четыре_ require the genitive singular. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Словарь-справочник "Русское литературное произношение и ударение" should be used for consultng in such cases.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i suppose that in the Old Russian language the "село" (and this is for sure) belonged to II declension, but  the "тело" 
(i think so, - as, f.e., the word "cлово" and this is for sure too) was reffered to VI declension.
About declensions in the Old Russian language:   1.  https://rus-et.ru/istoriya-yazyka/istoricheskaya-grammatika/sklonenie-sushhestvitelnyh-v-drevnerusskom-yazyke/
2.  https://rus-et.ru/istoriya-yazyka/istoricheskaya-grammatika/sklonenie-sushhestvitelnyh-v-drevnerusskom-yazyke-prodolzhenie/

Comment: Два мира, два Шапиро.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the numerals два (две), три, четы́ре, о́ба (о́бе), полтора́ (полторы́) are followed by nouns in the genetive singular which is те́ла and села́ - see the declension tables for [те́ло](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) and [село́](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0).

There are a few exceptions though, e.g. два шага́, три шара́ (while the regular genitive singular is ша́га, ша́ра: не сба́вить ша́га, оста́ться без ша́ра). Such words are said to have a distinct paucal form (счётная форма).